# Rename multiple image files in several folders with suffix + Creating a folder in which files will be moved

Tags: batch-file, executable, dos, batch-rename

I'm wondering how to create a script/batch executable file via MSDOS or VBS, which would do following.

I have one folder called '**Movies**', in this folder are several sub-folders with files like '**jpg,gif,png,srt,sub,avi,mp4,mkv**'.

***What I need is:***

0.) Every other file except of '**jpg,gif,png,srt,sub,avi,mp4,mkv**' with full or empty directory must be moved to trash or deleted.

1.)  Then I need to create under every sub-folder a new folder called '**Subtitles**'.

2.) Then to rename under every sub-folder '**jpg,gif,png**' file to '**Poster 1**', '**Poster 2**', '**Poster 3**' and so on... (no change on extension).

3.) Then I need to move the '**srt,sub**' file in to the created '**Subtitles**' folder.

4.) Then to rename the '**srt,sub**' file and also the folder itself which contains the movie file, according the movie file name. The movie file can have extension: '**avi,mp4,mkv**'.

5.) This executable file has to be run from the '**Movies**' folder and if it's possible also with results output on the screen (to see what was done).

So basically under folder '**Movie**' will be for example folder '**Pain (2011)**' which will contain '**Poster 1.jpg**', '**Poster 2.jpg**', '**Poster ?.jpg**' files a sub-folder called '**Subtitles**' in which will be the '**Pain (2011).srt**' file and at least the name of the folder itself and the subtitle file will be named after the movie file '**Pain (2011).avi**'. Of course all other files will be moved to trash or removed.

Every idea is much appreciated!

Thank you!

Sue

---

**OUTPUT:**

---

Press any key to continue . . .
File "monsieur_lazhar_.jpg" renamed to "Poster 1.jpg"
File "monsieur_lazhar__ver2.jpg" renamed to "Poster 2.jpg"
File "Poster 1.jpg" renamed to "Poster 3.jpg"
Press any key to continue . . .

---

/// in the folder are only 2 jpg files, and one of them is renamed twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set wantedExt=.jpg.gif.png.srt.sub.avi.mp4.mkv

rem I have one folder called 'Movies'
rem This executable file has to be run from the 'Movies' folder
cd /D "%~DP0"
echo BASE FOLDER: %cd%
rem in this folder are several sub-folders with files
set n=0
for /D %%a in (*) do (
   set /A n+=1
   cd "%%a"
   echo ==================================================================
   echo Processing folder: %%a

   rem 0.) Every other file except of 'jpg,gif,png,srt,sub,avi,mp4,mkv' must be moved to trash or deleted.
   for %%b in (*.*) do (
      if "!wantedExt:%%~Xb=!" equ "%wantedExt%" ECHO del "%%b" & echo File deleted: %%b
   )

   rem 0.5.) delete all folders before the 'Subtitles' folder is created
   for /D %%b in (*) do rd /S /Q "%%b"

   rem 1.) Then I need to create under every sub-folder a new folder called 'Subtitles'.
   ECHO md Subtitles
   echo Subtitles folder created

   rem 2.) Then to rename under every sub-folder 'jpg,gif,png' file to 'Poster 1', 'Poster 2', 'Poster 3' and so on... (no change on extension).
   set i=0
   for %%b in (*.jpg *.gif *.png) do (
      set /A i+=1
      ECHO ren "%%b" "Poster !i!%%~Xb"
      echo File "%%b" renamed to "Poster !i!%%~Xb"
   )
   rem PATCH to fix a bug in previous FOR command:
   if !i! neq 0 if not exist "Poster 1.*" (
      ren "Poster !i!.*" "Poster 1.*"
      echo ...and renamed back to "Poster 1"
   )

   rem 3.) Then I need to move the 'srt,sub' file in to the created 'Subtitles' folder.
   rem 4.) ... (to rename the 'srt,sub' file ... according the movie file name)
   rem The movie file can have extension: 'avi,mp4,mkv'.
   for %%b in (*.avi *.mp4 *.mkv) do set movieName=%%~Nb
   echo Movie name: !movieName!
   for %%b in (*.srt *.sub) do (
      ECHO move "%%b" "Subtitles\!movieName!%%~Xb"
      echo File "%%b" moved and renamed to "Subtitles\!movieName!%%~Xb"
   )

   rem 4.) ... (to rename the folder itself which contains the movie file, according the movie file name)
   cd ..
   ECHO ren "%%a" "!movieName!"
   echo Folder "%%a" renamed to "!movieName!"

)
echo ==================================================================
echo %n% FOLDERS PROCESSED
pause
```

Comment: Thank you, but please how can I use that?Because if I create a *.bat file with this script it makes nothing :(
I'm not that skilled person, I'm sorry :(
Sue

Comment: @user1868774: "5.) This executable file has to be run from the 'Movies' folder", that is: open a DOS Window, select the folder with `cd \Movies` or similar command, and execute the Batch file! I strongly suggest you to insert an `ECHO ` command before `del`, `md`, `ren` and `move` commands in the Batch file to just _display_ they. If everything seems correct after a test, you may delete the `ECHO`s to really execute the commands.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I don't have all the mentioned files 'jpg.gif.png.srt.sub.avi.mp4.mkv' in every single folder under the main folder 'Movies', can that be a problem? Because in the main folder 'Movies' are all this types of files and many more, but just those files should be kept, the rest should be moved to trash or removed. So it's not like all this files are in every single folder under the 'Movies' folder. In one sub-folder is for example an 'mkv,jpg' file and a 'txt', in second sub-folder is 'avi,png' file with an 'nfo'. And so on.. So the 'txt,nfo' should be removed.

Comment: And of course in those sub-folders can be more or less different files and also other sub-folders, which should be removed as well, before a new folder 'subtitles' is created. If the script was tested and it's working for you, please explain it to me like to a dummy what should be done :), because just to put the 'test.bat' file in to the folder 'Movies' and run it isn't enough, as nothing happens there, just the 'cmd window' opens for a second :/ Thank you very very much Aacini! Sue

Comment: @user1868774: Please note that "run the batch file from 'Movies' folder" is NOT the same than double-click on it! I modified the Batch file to correctly run when you double-click on it; I assumed this is what you done (you don't indicated that...). Please: 1-Copy the Batch file above again. 2-INSERT THE REAL PATH TO MOVIES FOLDER! 3-Double-click on it. If _tracing_ of commands in the screen is NOT what you want: Copy the screen contents (right-click title bar->Edit->Mark-> select the desired text and press Enter) and paste it as an edit in your question, and explain what is wrong with it...

Comment: Thank you again for your reply! I modified the start of the script to 'echo on' instead of 'off', else I would not get any results :/
Now the results are:
--------------
C:\Movies>xx.bat

C:\Movies>setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

C:\Movies>set wantedExt=.jpg.gif.png.srt.sub.avi.mp4.mkv

C:\Movies>rem I have one folder called 'Movies'

C:\Movies>REM PLACE THE RIGHT PATH TO MOVIES FOLDER HERE:

C:\Movies>cd /D C:\Movies

C:\Movies>rem in this folder are several sub-folders with files

C:\Movies>
C:\Movies>
--------------
The Movies folder is under 'c:\' to make it simpler, but nothing happened

Comment: @user1868774: I don't think this is so difficult... Copy the Batch file again (I modified it again) in your Movies folder and execute it. Copy the screen contents as I indicated above. Below your question there are "share|edit|delete|flag" buttons; click on EDIT, insert a descriptive line at end of your question (ie: "EDIT: Output of Aacini's solution program") and paste the screen contents. Add any comment if you wish. Click on "Save Edits" and post a new comment here with "Output of program added". Please, note that we can't help you if you don't help us to help you...

Comment: Hello again and again thank you for reply! Unfortunately it does not work for me, no output. I open the bat file, window opens for a second, then it closes, that's it. - I created a folder for you to get a better picture of my folder on my PC, it is only for test. Please go to: 'http://www.ulozto.net/xNmsKTt/movies-zip' Click on the yellow button stahuj(means download), fill the captcha and please download the file. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, but the 'bat' file does not work. It would be wonderful if you could run that as expected with the contidions above in that folder. Thanks

Comment: Wow! A very subtle bug found and fixed! Copy again the Batch file above and test it. In your example data there was NOT .avi file in "Elephant..." nor in "Start Trek..." folders. I don't know if this may happen in real data, but anyway I add code to manage this case. Remember that the Batch program above just DISPLAY the commands; if the output is what you want, delete the uppercase `ECHO` words so the commands be really executed.

Comment: I almost had a orgasm as I saw that it works on 80% :) It's absolutely wonderful! About your comment, the two mentioned movies, the script has not recognized, that in those folders are not AVI files but in one MKV and in second MP4, so it could not handle them as AVI files, would that be possible to fix? Other steps worked almost OK, posters were created, subtitles folder was created, but the subtitles file was not moved to the subtitles folder and also it was not renamed after the movies file, the folder itself was also not renamed after that movie file.

Comment: Anyway, the conditions are same, it does not matter if there is a real movie file in big size or just a dummy file, if it will work at you, it will work at me as well :) Two more comments: 1) the posters are wrong counted, they starting from number two (Poster 2, Poster 3 etc...) 2)Would it be also possible to delete all folders before the 'Subtitles' folder is created?? Thank you many many times Aacini, you are the best! If I just remember how much time could I save with this script in early days....ohh god :(  - What I've wrote above, the problem is just in the non AVI folders, other are OK!

Comment: If you want _modifications_ to your original request, state they as an edit in your question. For example, write: "In step 4) the "movie file name" is the file with .avi, .mkv or .mp4 extension". You had NOT mentioned that! Also, please include _all_ modifications at once. Finally, carefully check the errors you reported; for example, there is _no way_ that Posters start at number 2, _unless_ that a Poster 1 file exists. If you want to delete folders before a step, clearly state that as I indicated! If you can not edit your answer, post another comment with concise requests, NOT chatter...

Comment: Done, that are the only modifications to my original request, mentioned in step 0 and 4. I'm sorry, I thought that it is obvious that 'mkv' and 'mp4' file can be also a movie file. There will be no other request if this works, I promise :) Thank you Aacini! Sue

Comment: Changes as reply to new requests done. Check if new step 0.5) is what you wanted...

Comment: This is absolutely extraordinary! It work's now on 99%. Just one thing. As I mentioned earlier, there is a problem with renaming of the 'jpg.gif.png' files to 'Poster 1', 'Poster 2' etc. It counts right, but the number 1 (Poster 1) is at the end renamed again. Please see the output. In question section. Thank you!!!!!!!!!!! Sue

Comment: Please would you mind to check for the last time? Thank you and merry Xmas!

Comment: Yes, it seems that this is a _real_ bug, that means, a bug in FOR command. I need more time to check it...

Comment: Yes, it is a bug in FOR command! I added an `if` command (four lines) before `rem 3.) ...` to fix it. Please, report if the patch fails sometime and post the output in that case.

Comment: It works flawlessly!!! Unfortunately I have found two more issues, but I will open a new question I guess. Thank you Aacini for your hard work and support!